# Best Practice to run 1k user for stress testing

Tags: apache, jmeter

Scenario: I wanted to login , get cookies and use that cookies as auth for other api GET request for 10k user.
I an using Ultimate thread group with following rows
Start Thread Count: 1000
Initial Delay sec : 0
Startup Time : 1000
Hold Load for : 300
Shutdown :0

Does it make any difference on sever If I used single user login or I need to need to use 1k login details ? , In that case as cookies are stored under browser local storage , so I am using web driver sampler to get that , so for 1k how will it be possible.

Similarly said by client to do for 10K 20k and so on .

As I am new , figuring out what is best possible way to get this done , am I on correct direction , kindly mentor me out .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. `Does it make any difference on sever If I used single user login or I need to need to use 1k login details ?` we don't know, it depends on the particular server implementation. From the [black-box testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-box_testing) perspective I would go for "realistic" approach and use different credentials/cookies for different users
2. `In that case as cookies are stored under browser local storage , so I am using web driver sampler to get that` If after login you get the [Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) which can be used for authentication/authorization in an API request there is no need to use Selenium, with JMeter you can get the cookie value from the [Set-Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) response header  either manually using suitable [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) or automatically using [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-cookie-manager-advanced-usage-a-guide)